# Estimating $\int_0^1 x^{2n}(1-2x)^{2n}e^xdx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, proof-verification, estimation

To find a bound for $\int_0^1 x^{2n}(1-2x)^{2n}e^xdx$ I did the following:

\begin{align}
&x(1-2x)\leq\text{max}[x(1-2x)]\\
&x(1-2x)\leq\  1/8 \:\:\: \text  { the maximum occurs at $x=1/4$ }\\  
&x^{2n}(1-2x)^{2n}\leq  \left( 1/8 \right)^{2n}\\
& x^{2n}(1-2x)^{2n} e^x \leq  \left( 1/8 \right)^{2n} e^x\\
& \int_0^1 x^{2n}(1-2x)^{2n} e^x dx\leq \left( 1/8 \right)^{2n} \int_0^1 e^xdx\\
& \int_0^1 x^{2n}(1-2x)^{2n} e^x dx\leq \left( 1/8 \right)^{2n} (e-1)
\end{align}

I believe something is terrible wrong with that.

Comment: $x(1-2x)\le 1/8$ on $[0,1]$, but it's not true that $x^2(1-2x)^2\le1/8^2$ on $[0,1]$.

Comment: You are correct that something is not right.  That is because $x(1-2x)$ can be negative for $x\in[0,1]$.  The maximum value of $\big|x(1-2x)\big|$ for $x\in[0,1]$ is $1$, which is achieved when $x=1$.

Comment: How to fix this?

Comment: Maybe OP wants to prove $I_n\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$ (see his recent post)

Comment: Yes, I do, but I made this mistake. I think I need to choose a polynomial that is positive on $(0,1)$ for this method of estimation to work. Maybe If I pick a squared polynomial... But then the argument would't change and the problem would still persist.

Comment: One may use $I_n=\int_0^1 x^n(1-x)^n e^x~\mathrm dx$, then $\max_{x\in[0,1]}\{x^n(1-x)^n\}=(\frac 12)^n(\frac 12)^n=(\frac 14)^n\to 0$.

Comment: Yes, this is what beukers kind did, when he proved that $e^a \notin \mathbb{Q}$ to some rational $a$, but I wanted to try something different to see if this method would still work. Which barely dind't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When $x\in [0,1]$, $(1-2x)^{2n}\le 1$ and $e^x\le e$, by [first mean value theorem for definite integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Mean_value_theorems_for_definite_integrals),
\begin{align*}
I_n&\le\max_{x\in[0,1]}\{(1-2x)^{2n}e^x\}\int_0^1x^{2n}~\mathrm dx\\
&=\frac{e}{2n+1}\to0.
\end{align*}